Tikzpicture Multi-Edge
I want to create a multigraph. It's correct so far, but I want to have 3 edges from A to the same node B.
This is my latex code:
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
\node {A}
child { node {B}
    child { node {C} }
    child { node {D} }
    child { node {E} }
};
\end{tikzpicture}



Welcome! Are you able to complete your example so people can compile it straight away? Could you clarify what you want? If you draw 3 edges from A to B, won't you have 3 lines one on top of the other? I assume that's not what you want, but I'm not sure how else to understand your question.

Same result with Sandy's answer but with fewer modifications to the original code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
                    level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
                    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
  \node (a) {A}
    child
    { node (b) {B}
      child { node {C} }
      child { node {D} }
      child { node {E} }
    };
  \draw (a) to[out=-45, in=45] (b);
  \draw (a) to[out=-135, in=135] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This does the trick by naming the nodes A and B and drawing the two extra edges separately.  to[bend left] and to[bend right] would also work; use in and out if you need finer control of the curved edges.


Thank You! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

@VD3 Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem and upvoting answers which helped you.

Not sure if this is what you want, but here is a forest solution.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=1cm, l sep=1cm, parent anchor=south}
[A, name=A[B, name=B[C][D][E]]]
\draw(A)to[bend left](B)(A)to[bend right](B);
\end{forest}

\end{document}


Thank, at first I used the forest package, but then for me it was easier with tikz

s sep'=1cm, l sep'=1cm would be quicker.

@cfr: Thank you for pointing this out. I was unaware of this trick. For anyone interested, information can be found in section 3.6: Options and Registers of the Forest manual.
